# Fuel TimeOut Connection

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an issue with an app I am working on, especially on Galaxy 6.

What the app needs to do is to send a server request once a cann recieved or created therefor I am useing a BroadcastReceiver() which recieves the calls using

intent.action == "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"

statement and if its not true tn e it means call has been recieved, anyway my issue is that whenever a Call is recieved or started, My Fuel post Request most of the time getting timed out error exception!!

I tried replacing a library(amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking) but the exception returns, the issue seams to be only on that device cause on other devices it works great

My Code
override fun onIncomingCallReceived(ctx: Context?, number: String?, start: Date?)
{
MyApplicationClass.instance.printLog("State A0 ");

```
    MyApplicationClass.instance.upDateUserStatus(ctx,"RING",number,start?.time.toString(),"fasle",object : MyApplicationClass.PushReplacer
    {
        override fun replacedPush(jsonObject: JSONObject)
        {
            MyApplicationClass.instance.printLog("State A3 ");
            if(ctx != null && jsonObject != null) MyApplicationClass.instance.openNotif(ctx!!,jsonObject);
        }

    },true);

    Log.e("Phone", "onIncomingCajllReceived");
    Log.e("call", "A6");
}



    doAsync {

        ServerRequestName.change_user_status.httpPost()
                .header("Content-Type" to "application/json")
                .header("JWToken" to getJWToken(context))
                .header("encrypt" to Constants.instance.ENCRYPT)
                .body(bodyParameters(status,i_am_talking_with,timeStamp,report).toString())
                .timeout(10000)
                .timeoutRead(60000)
                .responseString{request, response, result ->
                    when(result)
                    {
                        is Result.Success->
                        {
                            val data : JSONObject = JSONObject(result.get());

                            if(data.has("error"))
                            {
                                uiThread {

                                    MyApplicationClass.instance.printLog("State A2 Data Sended Call Failed status1:$status talking with: $i_am_talking_with")
                                    //recieved data but had error in it//

                                    if(reConnectOnFail)
                                    {
                                        MyApplicationClass.instance.printLog("State A2 Data Sended Call Success status1:$status talking with: $i_am_talking_with")
                                        upDateUserStatus(context,status,i_am_talking_with,timeStamp,report,pushreplacer,false)
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                uiThread {

                                    MyApplicationClass.instance.printLog("State A1 Data Sended Call Success status2:$status talking with: $i_am_talking_with")

                                    if(data.has("push") && data.getJSONObject("push").length() != 0)
                                    {
                                        pushreplacer.replacedPush(data.getJSONObject("push"));
                                    }

                                }
                                //recieved data successfully//
                            }

                        }

                        is Result.Failure->
                        {

                            val data : JSONObject = JSONObject(result.get());

                            MyApplicationClass.instance.printLog("State A2 Data Sended Call Failed status:$status talking with: $i_am_talking_with");

                            uiThread {

                                if(reConnectOnFail)
                                {
                                    upDateUserStatus(context,status,i_am_talking_with,timeStamp,report,pushreplacer,false)
                                }
                            }

                            //recieved error//
                        }
                    }
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: what did you do to resolve the error? i'm experiencing this issue too in Galaxy S6. i'm using Fuel library.